Is there simple harmonic motion when a dielectric longer than the capacitor is inserted into the capacitor?
I’m trying to understand the mechanics of a dielectric being inserted into a parallel-plate capacitor. Suppose I have a parallel-plate capacitor with plate separation d and a dielectric slab of length $L_{dielectric}$ where $L_{dielectric} > L_{capacitor}$. The dielectric is partially inserted into the capacitor and can slide in and out. The capacitor is connected to a battery of emf $\epsilon $.
My question is: Under what conditions will the motion of the dielectric exhibit simple harmonic motion (SHM)? How do I derive the equations that describe this motion from first principles?

Possible duplicate.

If the lowest nontrivial order of the expansion of the potential around the equilibrium is quadratic, then small oscillations look like SHM
